# How to remove to ensure my form data object doesn't contain this unwanted characters when sent from lambda to ec2 using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I send my data via rest API(Ajax) from the form

```
data : JSON.stringify({
    formData : formData,
    action : "DoSomethin"
})
```

Arrives on lambda

`let {formData, action} = JSON.parse(event.body)`

Formdata is an object with correct structure(on lambda)

Then posting it to EC2 instance by:

```
let data = JSON.stringify(formData)
 post_req.write(data)
```

Then on EC2 on `req.body`

returns it with extra character which are:
At beginning: `{ '`
At end is:   `': '' }`

How to work with this form data so that it doesn't return this extra unwanted characters.

Comment: You mean the value of `req.body` is something like this: `{formData: ..., action: 'DoSomething'}`?

Comment: @Shihab sorry for late reply. Its is something like:
```{ '{"name":"fezekile", "age":25"}':''} ```

Expected is:
```{"name":"fezekile", "age":25"}```